# Save wrong data in controller (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers `Order` and `Meal`. This code made an error when I choose 2 the same meals:

`$scope.meal is undefined`

What can I do wrong?

```
    angular.module('mocs')
    .controller('ordersCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        'orders',
        'meals',
        'myService',
        function($scope, orders, meals, myService){
            $scope.orders = orders.orders;
            $scope.meal = myService.getOrder();

            if (!angular.isUndefined($scope.meal)) {
                orders.create({
                    meal_id: parseInt($scope.meal.id),
                    status: "ordered",
                });
            }
                                   ...
```

Even if error exist my wrong meal is saving to orders.

myService code:

```
.factory('myService', function() {
    var mealToOrder = {};

    return {
        setOrder: function(meal) {
          return mealToOrder.meal = meal;
        },
        getOrder: function() {
        return mealToOrder.meal;
        }
    };
});
```

my Factory:

```
angular.module('mocs')
.factory('orders', [ '$http',function($http){
     ...
 o.create = function(order) {
      return $http.post('/orders.json', order)
      .success(function(data){
        o.orders.push(data);
        order = '';
      });
    };

return o;
}]);
```

Comment: Your `myService.getOrder()` might be returning something even if it should not so `angular.isDefined($scope.meal)` always returns `true`. Perhaps, in that particular function, you can first make sure that function returns `undefined` when an error occurs.

Comment: What does `myService.getOrder()` do?  If you are making a HTTP request, then that would be running asynchronously.  In that case, your `if` statement would potentially execute before the `getOrder()` call has been completed.

Comment: Don't know how to break it to you man, if `mealToOrder = []`, then `mealToOrder.meal` is undefined.

Comment: How can I change that? Do I check mySerive returns always proper data? And what can I do with if statement to always execute in proper order?

Comment: shouldn't mealToOrder be an object i.e. mealToOrder = {} rather than an array as you have it now?

Comment: Why when I add different meals everything is good ? But when I add 2 the same , third meal is undefined ?